# Docker build exit status 127 (Errors were encountered while processing: libc6:amd64)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, python-3.7, ubuntu-20.04

Environment:

```
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
Kernel version 5.11.0-27-generic
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster as base

RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list \

    && apt-get update -y \

    && apt-get --fix-broken install -y libssl1.1 python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools cmake build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 gcc-10 wget libpq-dev \

    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    .
    .
    .
```

When executing the below command, I get the error logs which is displayed below.

```sh
sudo docker build -t ProjectImage:0.0.1 .
```

Error Logs

```
.
.
.
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 275 MB in 2min 22s (1937 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package gcc-11-base:amd64.
(Reading database ... 6840 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gcc-11-base_11.2.0-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-11-base:amd64 (11.2.0-4) ...
Setting up gcc-11-base:amd64 (11.2.0-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgcc-s1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 6845 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgcc-s1_11.2.0-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgcc-s1:amd64 (11.2.0-4) ...
Replacing files in old package libgcc1:amd64 (1:8.3.0-6) ...
Setting up libgcc-s1:amd64 (11.2.0-4) ...
(Reading database ... 6847 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.31-17_amd64.deb ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (Can't locate Term/ReadLine.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Term::ReadLine module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.28 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28 /usr/share/perl/5.28 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Readline.pm line 7.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...
Checking init scripts...
Unpacking libc6:amd64 (2.31-17) over (2.28-10) ...
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.31-17) ...
/usr/bin/perl: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libc6:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The build would fail, and error is logged as above.

I have tried updating my operating system, removing unused packages, using a fresh os to create the docker image, but it always returned this error. Is there something I'm missing out? Like some dependencies that is required or some incompatible versions of packages? Thank you

Comment: You're trying to do a large-scale OS upgrade inside your Dockerfile; the `libc6` package is a very-low-level system component.  Can you start your Dockerfile `FROM` a newer Python or Debian base that has the version you need already?

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried using `FROM python:3.9.7-slim-buster as base`, but still got into this error. I'm not too sure if the libc6 package that I need is in this version though, it's one of the newer ones on the [python docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) site. I did try 'FROM 3.10.0rc2-slim-buster as base' but I believe my syntax has an error, I got _repository does not exist_

Comment: @DavidMaze I found out I was careless and left out `python:` in my version 3.10 build. After using the newest version `FROM python:3.10.0rc2-slim-buster as base`, I was able to solve this issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @DavidMaze

The original dockerfile used an older version of python which contains an old version of `libc6`.

And as the dockerfile is used to do a large-scale update of the OS, it may cause issues with an outdated very-low-level system component.

Change the header of the dockerfile from
`FROM python:3.7-slim-buster as base`
to
`FROM python:3.10.0rc2-slim-buster as base`
which will use the python version with a newer version of `libc6`